# extract nonconvex hull from result of minkowski sum using boost

Tags: c++, boost, polygon, convex-hull, boost-polygon

http://postimg.org/image/sgl1q3vf5/
http://postimg.org/image/787d8ogy9/

As the pics shown above, I tried to calculate the minkowski sum of a polyline and a circle    and the resulting shape covers the area of the polygon Im trying to generate. I use the sample code from boost to implement the minkowski sum.
My question would be what are some efficient ways to extract the nonconvex hull(for lack of a better term) of the minkowski sum result(the boundary), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a non-convex hull, you'll have to implement [Alpha Shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape), I'm in the middle of implementing the algorithm for my project right now, unfortunately, it's not easy.

An alternative to implementing it yourself is to use [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/), it has an Alpha Shapes implementation (although that part of the library is GPL).

Comment: You can check my [project](https://github.com/voodooattack/ADWIF/blob/master/mapgenerator.cpp#L213) for sample code, it's not very well documented and it's certainly broken but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks.However, it seems that alpha shape can not add additional points that could be generated from polygon union,i.e.the point where the polyline in pic 1 changes angle.So what I need exactly is probably more than a non-convex hull.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, I've recently added Minkowski sum to my Clipper library:
http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Functions/MinkowskiSum.htm

[image]